# Formula to find the difference between two cells if a certain condition is true

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know the formula I need to use to subtract E100 from I100 if D100 and H100 are greater than 0. I want to know what the formula would be in Excel 2007 and where would it be applied.

Comment: the only formula you need is [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69AED7C9-4E8A-4755-A9BC-AA8BBFF73BE2)

Comment: like what would the whole formula be

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what should happen if D100 and H100 are **not** greater than zero. The following formula returns "Error" in that case, you can change "Error" to something more appropriate.

```
=IF(AND(D100>0,H100>0),I100-E100,"Error")
```

If the values in both cell D100 and cell H100 are greater than or equal to zero, the formula will return the value from cell I100 minus the value from cell E100, otherwise, it returns the string "Error".

fixer1234 points out in the comments that the following also works:

```
=IF(D100*H100>0,I100-E100,"Error")
```

This works, of course, I think it is a little less obvious what is being tested.
It is probably slightly faster, but I doubt that the difference would be noticeable.

Comment: or: `IF(D100*H100>0,I100-E100,"Error")`

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 I added this as an alternative.